# How to turn unicode character into \Uxxxxxxxx format in python 3

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, unicode, utf-8

I have an unicode character like  and I want to get back the \Uxxxxxxxx format. But until now, couldn't find an easy way. Already tried:

```
text = 

text.encode('utf-32').decode('utf-8')
returns error: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte

text.encode('utf-32').decode('unicode-escape')
returns ÿþ
```

How to make it return \U000XXXXX ? I know I can get the character from \U000XXXXX making:

```
string = "foo bar foo \U000XXXXX"
string.encode('utf-8').decode('unicode-escape')
returns "foo bar foo "
```

Comment: Note that `\U00xxxxxx` Is not UTF-32 at all.  UTF-32 is a binary format. `\U00xxxxxx` is an escape sequence, in plain ASCII.

Comment: This converter website confused me: https://www.branah.com/unicode-converter It says "convert to UTF-32". Sorry

Comment: Perhaps this is what you want? `''.encode('unicode-escape').decode('utf8')`

Comment: @metatoaster from that I get \xa9

Comment: You should be getting `'\\U0001f3c6'` as the output.  On the otherhand, the copyright symbol © would produce the output you got, i.e. `'©'.encode('unicode-escape').decode('utf8')`

Comment: Oh yeah, I was using that © for my bad. Thank my friend @metatoaster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a byte string:

```
>>> text = ''
>>> text.encode('unicode-escape')
b'\\U0001f3c6'
```

for a Unicode string:

```
>>> text.encode('unicode-escape').decode('ascii')
'\\U0001f3c6'
```